# Is Member Online?

Tags: add-on, members, statistics

Is there a native EE method to determine if a given member id is online? I'd rather not install an addon like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-online to do this.

Comment: Hi! I found another option for you. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the user seeing a page is authenticated, you can use some [global variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#alternative-syntax) like:

- `logged_in_member_id`
- `logged_in_group_id`

Or, if you want to check for an specific member, you can use the [Query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/index.html) and look for the collumn `member_id` on the table `exp_sessions`.

---

If you want to list the current logged members, use the [`member_names`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/statistics/index.html#member-names) variable pair of the Statistics Module:

```
{exp:stats channel="news|sports"}
    {member_names}
            {name}<br>
    {/member_names}
{/exp:stats}
```

Comment: Given a `member_id`, I want to know if that member is logged in to the EE website. It's for a "who's online" feature. If there is no native EE method to do this, I would probably prefer to use the add-on rather than the query module. Thoughts?

Comment: @ExpressionEngineNewbie, I don't know about any add-on to do this. I'm sorry.

But it doesn't look to hard to write one by yourself. You can grab a lot of member data with one single query, using Query Module or a custom addon.